# How to rename a attribute from a inherited type in XSD?

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation

```
<xs:complexType name="country">
  ...
  <xs:attribute name="zipcode" type="xs:string"/>
  ...
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="city">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="country">
      <xs:attributeRename from="zipcode" to="areaCode"/><!-- How to rename? -->
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

My "city" type is derived from "country". I want the attribute be renamed after the derivation. So my 2 XML objects will both be valid. Of course, I know I could just not use inheritance. But there are 10+ other attributes they share, and I don't want any duplication.

```
<country areacode="123"></country>
<city zipcode="456"></city>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at it from a context point of view, a city shouldn't inherit a country.

They could however both inherit a `location` type, which has all shared attributes and fields, and `city` and `country` could extend `location` for their own uses.

As far as I know, there is not way to rename or remove an attribute or a field from a type which you extend.